# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (custom class as property on a form)

Tags: c#

I have a WinForms app.

One of my forms has two properties which are custom classes i.e.

```
private cContact con;
private cIP ip;
```

In the LOAD event for the form I initialize these properties as follows -

```
this.con = new cContact();
this.ip = new cIP();
```

The parameterless Constructors for these classes simply populate the ID field and nothing else e.g.

```
class cContact
{
    private int _id;
    //...plus several other properties here

    public cContact()
    {
        this._id = 0;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get {return this._id;};
        set {this._id = value};
    }
}
```

Both classes contain multiple properties of which ID is just one (int).

Both classes contain Get / Set access modifiers for all properties.

Both classes have been in use for over a year without any issues, so I don't think the problem I am having is with the Classes themselves.

Then in my form I have an Event Handler which attempts to access the IDs in the two form properties (my custom classes)

```
private void Button_Click( . . .)
{
    int myID = this.con.ID
}
```

Yet I get a message saying

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

As the classes are instantiated in the Form's LOAD event, I fail to see why the button click event handler cannot access the class ID field.  Pretty sure this is going to be something simply when one of you point it out, but alas its had me scratching my head for too long already.

Comment: Are you sure it is the ID property that is null or is it the con that is null ?

Comment: Just a suggestion... you prefix members with `_` denoting them as member variables - so there's no need to pollute your code with `this` everywhere.  Consider also changing `con` to `_con` and `ip` to `_ip` (they are members also)... then you'll be `this` free :)

Comment: _"but alas its had me scratching my head for too long already."_ - stop scratching your head and press F9. We do not see enough relevant code and we do not see your code running, so we cannot but guess what is going wrong. Put a breakpoint in the click handler, inspect the variables, see which one is null, do a facepalm, fix it and close the question.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the setter of the property and you'll see when it is set to null. Or if it is not set at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what may have happened here is that the Forms designer has serialized the properties into the "Designer.cs"  file when you didn't want it to.

This will only happen if the properties are public, though.

If they *are* public and if you do not want the Forms designer to manage serializing and deserializing the properties' values, you have to use the [`DesignerSerializationVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx) attribute to tell it not to, like so:

```
[
    Browsable(false),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)
]

public MyType MyPropertyWhichMustNotBeSerialized
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

If this *is* what has happened, you should be able to see the unwanted serialization in the "Designer.CS" file. You can remove it, and then also add an attribute to the properties as shown above, and you should be ok then.